# check if string contains url anywhere in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if string contains a url using javascript i got this code from google

```
        if(new RegExp("[a-zA-Z\d]+://(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?").test(status_text)) {
          alert("url inside");
        }
```

But this one works only for the url like ["http://www.google.com"](http://www.google.com) and ["http://google.com"](http://google.com) but it doesnt work for ["www.google.com"](http://www.google.com) .Also i want to extract that url from string so i can process that url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 : No my question is little different, My input could have plain string, only url, or both text and url together.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try:

```
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(status_text)) {
        alert("url inside");
}
```

Comment: This one works, But i am trying to check it once its compltely typed i mean...when i type "http://www.go" this condition satisfies and shows alert...i want this script to wait until user enters complete url and then only show alert...by the way i m using keyup event to check.

Comment: @AmitPatil use blur event of the textbox, instead of keyup, sudhir's answer seems not extract that url, btw.

Comment: you can use blur event, so that once focus is lost from the textbox you can runs the code...

Comment: Yes thats the trick i can think of at last, but the reason i want it on keyup event is that...whenever i detect url i want to fire ajax call to extract details of the url in the meantime user can continue his typing...like it works on facebook status

Answer (score 3):

Sudhir's answer (for me) matches past the end of the url.

Here is my regex to prevent matching past the end of the url.

```
var str = " some text http://www.loopdeloop.org/index.html aussie bi-monthly animation challenge site."
var urlRE= new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?([^ ])+");
str.match(urlRE)
```

produced this output using node.js:

```
[ 'http://www.loopdeloop.org/index.html',
'http://',
 undefined,
'www.loopdeloop.org',
 undefined,
'l',
index: 11,
input: ' some text http://www.loopdeloop.org/index.html aussie bi-monthly animation challenge site.' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the regex to conditionally match on the scheme of the URL, like so:

```
var urlCheck = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z\d]+://)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?', 'i')
if (urlCheck.test(status_text) {
    console.log(urlCheck.exec(status_text));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg = new RegExp('([a-zA-Z\d]+://)?((\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?)', 'i')
if (reg.test(status_text)) {
    alert(reg.exec(status_text)[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
(?<http>(http:[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)
```

Comment: I don't think that matching the `www` seperately is really necessary here.