# How to check if string contain the "url or link" and retrieve it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, full-text-search

I have comment section of page where user can post the comments on uploaded content, I want to check if user has shared any url links in his comment.

for Example -

```
var comment = "To search more on this question you can look to http://stackoverflow.com/ "
```

Now How do I find out that it is URL link and retrieve that link?I would be great if I can find a way to do this in `Jquery` and `Java Script` but `PHP` is also acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570286/check-if-string-contains-url-anywhere-in-string-using-javascript

Comment: @ZanderRootman that question does not explain how to retrieve the URL from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this REGEX

```
((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_\/\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)
```