# How my button can move under each new added sections? For now it's placed above all sections

Tags: reactjs, button

How can I modify my code in order to get a dynamic `+Add Invitee` button which will move down the last section each time you add fields? For now, it appears above all blocks.

```
export default function App() {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState("");

  return (
      <>
      <button type="button" onClick={addInvitee}>
        +Add Invitee
      </button>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {invited.map(({ age, email, id, location, name }, index) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5">
              <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold">
                Names:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={name}
                  placeholder="Names"
                  name="name"
                  onChange={updateInvitee(id)}
                />
              </label>                
                ...
              {!!index && (
                <button type="button" onClick={() => removeInvitee(id)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my:
[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-empty-new-fields-by-clicking-on-a-button-forked-e7lret?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: do you mean the `+Add Invitee` button?

Comment: Hi, yes (in the picture it's +Add menu, but it's a mistake, I will change it)

Comment: do you mean something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-empty-new-fields-by-clicking-on-a-button-forked-izlolx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Elnatanvazana Exactly!

Comment: i posted it as an answer. if you find it helpful and it fixed your issue, please consider to mark it as the right answer. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you just need to take the button down under the form.

```
export default function App() {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState("");

  return (
      <>
      
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {invited.map(({ age, email, id, location, name }, index) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5">
              <label className="mr-3 h-6 text-md font-bold">
                Names:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={name}
                  placeholder="Names"
                  name="name"
                  onChange={updateInvitee(id)}
                />
              </label>                
                ...
              {!!index && (
                <button type="button" onClick={() => removeInvitee(id)}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </form>
       <button type="button" onClick={addInvitee}>
        +Add Invitee
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

also you can style the button or wrap it with a div for more complex styling to achieve the example from the photo you shared.

here is alink for a working example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-add-empty-new-fields-by-clicking-on-a-button-forked-izlolx?file=/src/App.js)