# REACT- How do I raise a warning if a specific input field is empty with Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, yup

I'm creating a multi step form and I want to raise an error if my field  `'title'` and `invited[0].name`( at least one invited should be written) are not filled in my form such as '*this field is required*' in red under the input box. I use `Yup` but doesn't seem working... Any ideas ?

```
export default function Information() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    setUserData((userData) => ({
      ...userData,
      [value]: checked
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col ">
      <div>
        Title :
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={userData["title"]}
          name="title"
          placeholder="Title"
        />
      </div>
      ...
  );
}
```

In validation.js :

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
import menus from "../data/menus.json";
const {
  menus: { title, invited }
} = menus;

export default [
  Yup.object().shape({
    [title]: Yup.string().required(`Title required`),
    [invited.name]: Yup.string().required(`At least one participant required`)
  })
];
```

menus.json:

```
{
  "menus": [
    {
      "id": "Menu1",
      "title": "Soup",
      "price": 4,
      "invited": [
        {
          "name": "Jose Luis",
          "location": "LA"
        },
        {
          "name": "Smith",
          "location": "New York"
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Here is my [sandboxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/mulit-step-form-pgw0ei?)

Answer (score 2):

- You have to use [`Yup.array()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#array) to define the schema for the array (`invited`) and [`.of()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#arrayoftype-schema-this) to
  target each item of the array (which is an object in your case).

Change the validation.js to

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
import menus from "../data/menus.json";
const {
  menus: { title, invited }
} = menus;

export default Yup.object().shape({
        title: Yup.string().required(`Title required`),
        invited: Yup.array()
            .of(
                Yup.object().shape({
                    name: Yup.string().required('Required') // these constraints take precedence
                })
            )
            .required('At least one participant required') // these constraints are shown if and only if inner constraints are satisfied
            .min(1, 'At least one participant required'),
    });
```