# REACT- Turn my code using Formik or TextField if I want to use Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, yup, formik-material-ui

how can I turn my following code using `Formik` or `TexField` in order to create a multi step form  (in such a way I can use Yup afterwards) ? I tried both but it's not working...

```
export default function Information() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    setUserData((userData) => ({
      ...userData,
      [value]: checked
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col ">
        Title :
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={userData["title"]}
          name="title"
          placeholder="Title"
        />
      </div>
      ...
  );
}
```

Here my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/mulit-step-form-pgw0ei?)

Here what I'm expected to have if I use Yup:[image]

Comment: This is a big part of code to add. the big idea if to create a Formik steps and to wrap them with parent Formik (if you need exp I can try to add it here

Comment: @yonizilberman is there a way to add it in the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/mulit-step-form-pgw0ei?) just for an example cause I tried to use Grid, Formik but it's not working... Plus, I've already my steps. I really don't know if I have to modify the all thing.

Comment: @yonizilberman I've opened a new issue, this time I have modifed a lot of thing it has been working but when I include Forms.jsx in Form.jsx then it's not working at all... Check here please [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078650/react-how-do-i-raise-a-warning-if-a-specific-input-field-is-empty-with-yup) the link for the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/mulit-step-form-pgw0ei?) is the same

Comment: There are a lot of miss imports and wrong paths...